# container class member interaction

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'd like to get some advice on how I can improve my overall program design.

I have a main class which has two members that frequently need to interact with each other. This container-like class has an `Initialize()` function which initializes both of the members, and other functions which provide access to the outside world:

```
class Foo {
public:
    bool InitializeAandB();
    void UseFoo();

private:
    TypeA a;
    TypeB b;
};
```

At some point after `UseFoo()` is called, `a` will need to call one of `b`'s public functions. So, let's say TypeA has a member function like this:

```
void TypeA::Function() {
    if (true) {
        TypeB *bpointer;
        bpointer->Interact(); // Need pointer to b here.
    }
}
```

`TypeA` and `TypeB` are separate entities and cannot be combined into a single class. It just so happens that these separate entities need to interact with each other at various times.

I don't want to make `a` and `b` public because they shouldn't be visible from the outside world. Adding `TypeA` and `TypeB` as friends in `Foo` seems like a hacky fix. Also not ideal because then both `TypeA` and `TypeB` need to know about `Foo` when they only need to know about each other. Same goes for public `GetA()` and `GetB()`  accessor functions.

A third option is to add a `TypeB*` member to `TypeA` and a `TypeA*` member to `TypeB` which are set during `InitializeAandB()`. But this seems redundant on some level, like I'm missing a better overall design.

Is there a better way to design this?

Comment: look into the "friend" keyword.

Answer (score 1):

How about passing `TypeB *` as an argument to `TypeA::Function()` (and vice versa)?

Comment: It will make coupling tighter. Not a good solution. But that depends on what are `A` and `B` actually.

Answer (score 1):

**Dependency injection** is the only option I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @CreativeMind. You should use DI container here.

Refactor initialization phase into separate class, fill your DI container with instances of `A` and `B`. Extract interfaces from their implementation and place it as a contract somewhere. Now they are services and can ask container for each other.

`Foo` can now use `A` and `B` the same way - via container.